# Delegate method indexpath not found

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have implemented this delegate method for UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, but when attempting to dequeue the cell there, I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I also get this if I try to do this: `let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! RQTTipCell`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TipCell", for: indexPath) as! RQTTipCell
        let height = self.proxyView!.tipCollect.contentSize.height
        let width = cell.bagRatio.multiplier / height
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    }
```

This indexPath should be correct, but does not seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the error meaning, it means that the item you are trying to fetch from the array is not available.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

You are trying to fetch something at index `1` but your array size is `[0 .. 0]`

Now **why is it happening?**

- The simple explanation would be when you are trying to fetch the Cell from `CollectionView`, it not available at that movement. The reason would be the Cell has been added yet.

Now how to fix, use `optional` cast here.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TipCell", for: indexPath) as? RQTTipCell {
       let height = self.proxyView!.tipCollect.contentSize.height
       let width = cell.bagRatio.multiplier / height
       return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    } else {
       // default CGSzie
       CGSize()
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would it be asking for size of a cell that isn't visible?

Comment: Good question. Can you check that cell identifier is correct?

Comment: It is correct. "TipCell" is used to register the cell.

Comment: Can you try `cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! RQTTipCell`? this will return the cell if exitis at paricular index path

Comment: That also fails.